# function static::created does not save properly Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-api

So I have 2 tables: Item and Product. An Item `hasMany` Products and a Product `belongsTo` an Item.

Products migration:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('hashed_id')->nullable()->unique();
    $table->bigInteger('item_id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('state')->default(1);
    $table->decimal('price');
    $table->string('slug')->nullable()->unique();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

For the hashed_id I use the following package: https://packagist.org/packages/hashids/hashids to create a hashed id to show in the url.

Product.php

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function ($product) {
        $productId = $product->id;
        $hashids = new Hashids("", 10, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890');
        $hashedId = $hashids->encode($productId++);

        $slug = Str::slug($product->item->slug . '-' . $hashedId);

        $product->hashed_id = $hashedId;
        $product->slug = $slug;
    });

}
```

ProductsController.php

```
public function createSelfProduct(Request $request)
{
    $product = auth()->user()->products()->create([
        'item_id' => $request->item_id,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'price' => $request->price,
    ]);

    // create the product and show seller info
    return new ProductResource($product->load('user'));
}
```

What I'm trying to do is that when a user creates a new product, it should get the `slug` from the item model, put the `$hashedId` behind it and save that to the db. Now, when I do a post request via Postman, I get the desired result, as `hashed_id` and `slug` are saved. But when I check the database, both `hashed_id` and `slug` are NULL. Only the `item_id`, `user_id` and `price` are saved. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you considered using an Observer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `created` event means the Model has already been created. This is not before save, but after it has been saved. If you alter anything at this point you will need to save the record again.

**Simply:** You forgot to call `save` on your model instance to save the changes after you altered it.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has a convenient way of handling this with Observers

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers

```
php artisan make:observer ProductObserver
```

Then in Observers/ProductObserver.php

```
public function created(Product $product) {

    $product = ''; // whatver you need to do here. $product is an instance of Product model

    // Dont forget to save your model after modifying
    $product->save();

}
```

Comment: Although this was not the answer that solved my problem, I will look into the Observer pattern more, thanks a lot.