# how to auto update product status in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to auto-update product status as 'Not Available' when product `Qty <= 0` and update status as 'Reorder level' `Qty > 1 && Qty <= 5`  using trigger function or using the model. how do I solve this problem?

**This my product table.**

```php
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('ProductID');
  $table->string('Name');
  $table->string('Brand');
  $table->mediumText('image')->nullable();
  $table->string('Description');
  $table->string('Warranty');
  $table->integer('Price');
  $table->integer('Qty');
  $table->string('Status')->nullable()->default("In Stock");
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('AdminID');
  $table->foreign('AdminID')->references('EmpID')->on('users');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: you need to create a observer class for `product` and run that function once product get deleted , created or updated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as observer product class
(more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58892374/4780438 )
or simply add observe action like this to product model class

```
 protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        
        /*
         *
         * retrieved : after a record has been retrieved.
         * creating : before a record has been created.
         * created : after a record has been created.
         * updating : before a record is updated.
         * updated : after a record has been updated.
         * saving : before a record is saved (either created or updated).
         * saved : after a record has been saved (either created or updated).
         * deleting : before a record is deleted or soft-deleted.
         * deleted : after a record has been deleted or soft-deleted.
         * restoring : before a soft-deleted record is going to be restored.
         * restored : after a soft-deleted record has been restored.
         *
         * */
        
        static::saved(function ($model){
            if ($model->Qty <= 0) {
                $model->Status = 'Not Available';
                $model->save();
            }
            
            if ($model->Qty <= 5 && $model->Qty >= 1) {
                $model->Status = 'Reorder level';
                $model->save();
            }
        });
    }
```

You can read more in docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers

Comment: can you explain further. i can't solve this

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i use your code. but not updating. i use this in appServiceProvider also. `public function boot()
    {
        product::observe(productObserver::class);
    }`  and change config.app.php and use your code in product model. but I can't solve this.

Comment: post here your's Post.php model

Comment: `namespace App\Models;use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class product extends Model
{use HasFactory;protected $primaryKey = "ProductID";
 public function users(){return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'EmpID');}
protected static function boot(){
 parent::boot();
static::saved(function ($model){
if ($model->Qty <= 0) {$model->Status = 'Not Available'; $model->save();}`  this is product.php